# How to connect Loop Energy Saver to Landis Gyr gas meter?

Tags: smart-home, energy-monitoring-systems

I've ordered [Loop Energy Saver](https://www.your-loop.com/) to monitor my energy efficiency at home, both devices for electricity and gas, however I'm having trouble with installation of my gas kit since my gas meter is different as demonstrated on the [installation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfdLxxaBzAc). Is it possible to connect Loop Gas kit to my type of meter?

Here is the picture of my gas meter:

[image: Landis Gyr gas meter, National Grid, UK]

Answer (score 7):

As per [Loop FAQ](https://www.your-loop.com/faqs) we can read that:

> If you have a gas meter with an electronic/digital LCD display and/or it is made by Landis & Gyr then unfortunately Loop is not yet compatible with this type of gas meter.

Therefore all of the gas meter with an electronic/digital LCD displays are not supported (yet).

In order to be Loop compatible, their support suggested that the gas monitor would require either revolving digits for optical detection or a rotating magnet in a revolving drum for magnetic detection, and a gas meter with only an LCD has neither.

Therefore the options are either to change the gas provider or give back the monitor device to the supplier in order to refund.